# Can I use a static web page as an API proxy, with HTTP, HTML or JS redirect?

Tags: rest, http

I have an API that needs to change its address. Ideally, I wouldn't bother with updating the client. Can I just put a simple static page with a redirect on the old address - or even just an HTTP redirect?

I know there are API gateways and whatnot that can do this job but I can't immediately find the problems with the simpler solution, even after some googling.

I know it's probably going to be obvious in hindsight - so please enlighten me, why won't an HTTP redirect, a meta redirect tag or `window.location` work?

Comment: If it's under a domain name, I would just put a record on the domain to point to the appropriate IP. If you still own the previous IP but want to redirect traffic away from it, then it may be time to look into http status codes 302, 303, 307, and 308. No need for a page really, this can be done with just HTTP headers (usually supported by common webservers like nginx or apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything consuming a web API is unlikely to process meta data in HTML documents or execute JavaScript embedded in them.

They should respect an HTTP 301/302/307/308 redirect.

Comment: Oh yes, that's the obvious in hindsight part - that HTML/JS needs to be processed by the client. But so far it's looking like HTTP redirect might work, which is surprisingly little work!

Comment: OK, the downside of HTTP redirect is that it only works on the whole domain level, so it may not actually be applicable in my case, depending on whether all the other apps on the same domain are already decommissioned.

Comment: HTTP redirects operate on a per URL level, not on the whole domain (although a hosting arrangement might give you a restricted ability to configure them).